# IDEA 2022.1 - avoid prompt when killing node.js run config?

Tags: intellij-idea

Recently switched over to 2022.1 from 2021.3 (where this problem was not present).

When you kill a Node.js server run configuration in the latest version of IDEA, it now prompts you `Terminate batch job (Y/N)?` - how can I can I stop IDEA from waiting for this prompt?

This prompt causes a few different issues:

- have to find the Run tool window and answer "Y" when restarting the run config (can work around this by hitting `Ctrl`+`F2` to terminate the process).
- causes IDEA to hang if you exit with `File | Exit` or `Alt`, `f`, `x` while a process is still running (can't use `Ctrl`+`F2` to kill it either, have to kill the IDEA process to exit).

Is there any way to tell the latest version of IDEA to not wait for the prompt when terminating the run configuration?

---

Workaround outlined in the answer helps both of my issues. Note that you must select the `node_modules/npm` directory for the `package manager` (I initially thought I was supposed to set it to the parent directory of the `.exe`).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's [WEB-55457](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-55457/Prompt-to-Terminate-Batch-Job-when-debugging-NPM-scripts-if-usin) fixed in 2022.1.1. As a workaround, select path to the npm installation folder instead of the path to the binary in the Package manager field in the run configuration or Node.js IDE settings.